# Terminal: What is the shortcut to clean your command line

Tags: macos, terminal, shortcuts

If I have this:

```
$ bla bla bla bla
```

Is there any shortcut for Terminal (MacOS) to clean the entire line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command to discard (kill) the whole line is not usually assigned a keyboard shortcut. `Ctrl-U` will only kill from the beginning of the line to the cursor.

Press both `Ctrl-U` (prefix) and `Ctrl-K` (suffix) to remove the whole line, no matter where the cursor is.

[Here's](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Killing.html) a bash reference with the different commands and their default keyboard shortcuts.

You can assign a keyboard shortcut to `kill-whole-line` by editing `~/.inputrc`. Add the following line:

```
"\C-k": kill-whole-line
```

This will assign `Ctrl-K` the "kill whole line" command.

Comment: you're correct for most linuxes, but on OSX C-u clears the whole line not just behind the cursor position.

Comment: @Ted Naleid: In Snow Leopard it just removes from the beginning of the line to the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I use zsh, not the default bash shell, and in zsh it deletes the whole line.  Deleting the whole line (regardless of cursor position) is also the behavior in cocoa-based controls (such as the firefox address bar), so I assumed that was the bash behavior too.  Just tested in bash shell and the behavior described by Daniel in the answer matches.

Comment: @Ted Naleid: I googled zsh. Looks quite interesting. I might install it on my macbook after the exams :)

Comment: @Nerian No need to download anything. Change your shell in *System Preferences » Accounts » Right-click your account*, or change the Terminal shell in Terminal preferences.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I installed the last version using Homebrew. zsh 4.3.11. And I used the a zshrc conf from http://grml.org/zsh/ . I like the sequential tab :)

Answer (score 10):

Following is for Linux bash, but I suppose this should work for Mac also:

Clear input line:

```
Ctrl + U
```

Another trick is just:

```
Ctrl + C
```

Comment: It works, perfect :)

Comment: @Nerian: Please don't forget to mark your question as answered!

Comment: works perfect. thx!

Comment: because everything should be weird on mac, it is `command +K`, and `Ctrl + C`

Comment: This no longer appears to work on MacOS in 2023.  I've not found any way to clear the line other than holding backspace until it's cleared.

Comment: @PaulSlocum, this particular answer is for _bash_, and yes it still works. You probably are using some other shell, perhaps default _zsh_?